# What factors contribute to ExecuteReader's duration?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

We have an application which gives every impression of being bottlenecked on poor database response. Neither the database nor the application server are heavily loaded, but the application is spending considerable time making queries via ExecuteReader.

We are measuring two things: batch and statement duration in SQL Server Profiler, and the time between invoking ExecuteReader and disposing it. Consumption of the data is 'trivial' ie. simply reading data into a list of dictionaries.

Duration recorded by the Profiler is often considerably less than that recorded by the application. These queries return only a few rows (usually one) so the time taken to consume the resultset should be tiny.
But we've seen instances of a 150ms query (as recorded by the profiler) being recorded as over 1700ms by the application.

Environment:

- It's not our infrastructure.
- It's live, so we can't attach a profiler/debugger.
- The application server at least is virtualised. The DB is a cluster.
- SQL Server 2008R2 and Windows Server 2008R2.

An obvious culprit is network latency, but `ping` indicates that latency from app to DB server is consistently less than 1ms.

The connection is reused for multiple queries, so Open()-time overhead should already have been accounted for separately. I would *expect* this to rule out authentication delays during ExecuteReader, but perhaps I'm wrong about that?

**What other things should we investigate?** What other things might ExecuteReader wait upon?

Comment: "The connection is reused for multiple queries" - that has me worrying - *how* or *why* is the connection being reused?

Comment: Multiple queries in the same NHibernate session, specifically.

Comment: The connections are never shared between threads and we have MARS turned off (queries are only ever run consecutively). Some parts of the application depend upon temp tables, which are lost when the connection is closed, so retaining the connection across multiple queries is sometimes *required*. It's rare for any connection to live for more than a few seconds though.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It should simply be a `SqlConnection` that is opened and then multiple `SqlCommand`s are executed using that connection without closing it between each query. This is fine as it is the same thing as multiple batches via `GO` in SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we've seen instances of a 150ms query (as recorded by the profiler) being recorded as over 1700ms by the application.

How, exactly, is the app recording the duration? Using `StopWatch`, or something of that nature? Or from the client statistics as reported by [SqlConnection.RetrieveStatistics()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.retrievestatistics.aspx)?

Have you checked the wait type fields for the request running the query? In the [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) DMV there are four fields that have info that might be useful here: `wait_type`, `wait_time`, `last_wait_type`, and `wait_resource`. It is possible that even with the query returning the results quickly to SQL Server internally, it still needs to devote a thread to sending those results back to the caller.

Also, some things to try just to help narrow down possibilities:

- turn off connection pooling. In the [ConnectionString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx), use `Pooling=false;`. This will still allow for multiple queries on the same connection (hence won't interfere with the use of temporary tables). Yes, it will slightly increase overall time as it will require authentication for each connection, but it will rule out something getting "stuck".
- if possible (and not already doing so), specify `CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` in the call to `ExecuteReader()`. This prevents local caching of the entire row when calling `SqlDataReader.Read()` which helps when there are large string and/or binary values that you aren't even retrieving, or if there are lots of columns and you are only grabbing a few.

Comment: Thanks, turning off connection pooling hadn't occurred to me, and would certainly help highlight any issues around setting up the connection too! We don't see much in the way of waits, but 'async network I/O' sometimes pops up as a major one when sending back large numbers of rows.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `Async Network IO` means that the app isn't retrieving the results quickly enough. So the latency could be in the app itself, for whatever reason. What are you doing with the values per each row?

Comment: In most cases we buffer it as a list of dictionaries, or similar structure. Profiling has never pointed at this as a bottleneck. Even for larger resultsets we tend to convert the data into objects ASAP and then close the reader.

Comment: Measurement is handled via Miniprofiler, which almost certainly uses Stopwatch under the covers.

Comment: I haven't used miniprofiler, but it might be a slightly different metric than what SQL Server Profiler is measuring. You might want to look at the client stats reported by `SqlConnection`, just to get a 2nd opinion ;-).

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into doing that too, with a tool specialised for hunting down this problem! :)  Re: Miniprofiler, it's mostly a request-tracing and logging framework so what really matters is where it starts and stops the Stopwatch, which in this case appears to be before ExecuteReader() and after the corresponding Dispose() respectively.

Comment: @AlexDavidson Hopefully the acceptance of this answer means that you figured it out, which is great! If you don't mind, can you please share what you found and what you tried. I would like to update my answer with what suggestions helped and which didn't so much. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't been told exactly what the problem was, but it's been fixed now... We wrote a tool https://github.com/BluewireTechnologies/db-latency to time the various stages of the request in greater detail and it demonstrated that the latency spikes affected the ExecuteReader call specifically, even for 'no-op' queries like getting the SQL Server version, which helped rule out application-side delays. Opening the connection barely figured, although at other sites which were working fine it accounted for the bulk of the (much reduced) time.

Comment: @AlexDavidson Interesting, and thanks for posting that info. I will check out that tool when I get time. It is probably too late now, but if it happens again, a good test would be to do `SELECT @Version = @@VERSION;` and set up a `SqlParameter` with a direction of `Output`, and then use `ExecuteNonQuery()`. It might help narrow down the issue further if you can compare it against the same `SELECT @@VERSION` via a `SqlDataReader`. Would also help to know how much free memory is on the system, and if SQL Server has access to all CPUs or is constrained to only some (i.e. how many worker threads).

Comment: Ooh, good to know, thanks again! Re. CPUs and threads, sadly I don't think we have that level of access to the cluster.